# general doubt in erratic urdf

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write a urdf for a rover which is like erratic robot in some aspects,but it is very big compared to it.So i tried changing urdf file of erratic  to suit my rover.However i was not able to change the wheel of the erratic robot because it is a stl file.Can you suggest me anyways to change the stl file to make it bigger.i am a newbie to ros.pardon me if the question is trivial.thanking you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9310/general-doubt-in-erratic-urdf/) by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2011-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, there are a couple of things you can do. The easiest one to try is to specify a scale parameter on the mesh (see http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/Link for reference on URDF). Another option is to replace the mesh with a primitive cylinder shape which should work equally well.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on 2011-03-06**:
i am really sorry for the previous comment.I got it working.there is some mistake in my syntax.Really sorry for disturbing you..Thanking you..

**Comment by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on 2011-03-06**:
I tried that but i was not able to parse it.It is showing the following error.Invalid  tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/common/xacro/xacro.py '/home/avinash/ros/raven_robot_model/urdf/raven.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [1].  raise XacroException("included file [%s] generated an error during XML parsing: %s"%(filename, str(e)))

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-03-06**:
Execute "gedit `rospack find erratic_description`/urdf/erratic_wheel.xacro" and modify lines 36 and 44 to have scale attribute, e.g.  to make the wheel twice as large.

**Comment by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on 2011-03-06**:
Hi could you tell me how to specify a scale parameter on the mesh...Thanking you...